# In .net core ,Can http.sys be used as reversed proxy server?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, http.sys

In .net core Can http.sys be used as reversed proxy server to Kestrel or other internal server ?

Comment: Check the docs: [HTTP.sys web server implementation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: there is another MS project, [`YARP`](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy), that is *specifically* intended for this scenario